# Which is better auto register schema or manual register in confluent schema registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to understand the confluent schema registry and evolution of schema in it. I couldn't find which is better among the following. What is preferred to use and when ? What are the pros and cons of the two approaches ?

1. Producer Auto registering the schema
2. Manually register the schema using api

Comment: Disabling auto-registration has to be set on a client-by-client basis, so there really isn't a clean way to force manual registration

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the environment and your organization....
There is no better in this case...

1// auto register on producing messages is more suitable for development environments , so you might give developers self service and working with schema registry without the overhead to administer the schema registry

2// while letting schema registry to be evolved and registered only through the api, by authorized authorities, might be more suitable for production, where you have more strict and stable structure of the messages and schemas and won't want a rouge producer to cause you a down time

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a rouge producer? if all producers are given network access to the Topic and schema registry, how could there be a rouge producer?